# Chai-http request returning undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, mocha.js, chai

Below is my code:

server.js

```
const app = express();
app.listen(port, () => {
  logger.info(`App running on http://localhost:${port}`);
});

export default app;
```

test.js

```
import server from "../../src/index.js";

chai.use(chaiHttp);

describe("GET Balance API Tests", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    const userBalance = mockUserBalances;
  });

  it("should return correct value", async () => {
    const res = await chai.request(server).get("/balance/user-1");
    console.log(res.status);  // this correctly returns 200
    res.status.should.equal(200);  // this throws an error stating res is undefined
  });
});
```

What am I doing wrong here? Why is res always undefined whenever I try to make any assertion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `res.status` is "200", I don't think it would have a `should` attribute on it. I think the correct assertion should be like this:

```js
expect(res).to.have.status(200);
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked! May I ask why though? I have also tried res.should.have.status(200) but it returns the same error (Cannot read property 'have' of undefined), implying that it treats res as undefined

Comment: If the error says "Cannot read property 'have' of undefined", it actually implies that `res.should` is undefined, because the code failed to read 'have' from `res.should`. If `res` was undefined, the error would have been "Cannot read property 'should' of undefined". Does that make sense?

Comment: Got it, that means I am probably not importing the 'should' properly, thank you so much!

Comment: It is the `expect` that gives you the `should` and `to` and `have`, etc... `res` itself is just a response.